# password_verify is false on true password

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, password-hash

I am currently experimenting with the password_hash() and password_verify() method..

So I tought I go ahead and create a little login/register with it.

The problem is whenever I open the login the output is:

> *failed*

And I have no clue why.. I already set the length of the password field in my database to 255 but it is still not working.

***This is my register.php***:

```
<?php
require_once('db.php');

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['password']);

$p = password_hash($_GET['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $p);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
$db->close();
?>
```

***And my login looks like this:***

```
<?php
session_start();

error_reporting(0);

require_once('db.php');

function e($input) {
    return htmlspecialchars($input, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['password']);

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
$row = $stmt->fetch();

if (!empty($row)) { 
    if (password_verify($_GET['password'], $row['password'])) {
        echo 'success'; 
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo 'failed';
    }
} 
else 
{
    echo "This user does not exist"; 
}

$stmt->close();
$db->close();
?>
```

I don't know how to get this working :/

Comment: How big is the column where you're storing the hashed password? It must be at least 60 characters wide.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I set it already to 255

Comment: ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I noticed that, but then noticed they use `$_GET['password']` in the comparison.  They also use `bind_result()` to those 2 variables and then use the values from `$row` from the `fetch()`.

Comment: While you're debugging code, you really shouldn't have `error_reporting(0);` since that _disables_ all warnings, notices, errors etc, making it much harder to debug.

Comment: Actually, as it was just pointed out to me, you're not using the escaped passwords and usernames anywhere. You can eliminate all of that code.

Comment: I will accept the answer below.. Stackoverflows says I can accept in 5 minutes.

Comment: You may want to consider returning to some of your previous questions and doing the same.

Comment: Yeah I should start doing this.. I am going to do this right now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$stmt->fetch();` **does not** return data. It **binds data** to variables defined in `bind_result()`.

So after `$stmt->fetch()` you will have username in `$username` and password in `$password`.

So, what really should be compared is:

```
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    // here 
    if (password_verify($_GET['password'], $password)) {
        echo 'success'; 
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo 'failed';
    }
} 
else 
{
    echo "This user does not exist"; 
}
```

Comment: Ahhh... Thank you! I didn't know that fetch just binds the data and does not return it..
It works now!

Comment: @darby -  This is a perfect example why it's bad to turn error reporting off while developing. This would have thrown a notice about trying to use a boolean as array, pointing you in the right direction. It's better to have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` during development